# Send to FSI and Xamarin Studio for Windows

Tags: xamarin-studio, f#-interactive

Although I can open the F# Interactive window in Xamarin Studio for Windows, I can't send F# code from a fsx or fs editor to the interactive window.  There's no key binding such as "Send code to interactive" to be bound to the Alt+Enter keys and there's no context menu for the same when the code is selected in the window.  Is there some other way to enable the key binding?

Thanks